# Samples of legal contracts for contractors (freelancers)

Tags: contracts

Is there a good resource where I could find a quality contract sample which I can use for my clients?

Ideally it would be a contract for IT expert, not plumber (since I found many contracts like that) :).

I really need it be quality one to cover all aspects of the work.

Comment: I just saw this link http://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/169/where-can-i-find-good-contract-templates?rq=1 which I missed before. If this one does not help, I will get back here. For now, this topic can serve as a reference.

Comment: Just an FYI I've added a new answer to that older question. Hope it helps :)